# Does anyone know a feedback circuit (or IC) for doing a high voltage resonance sweep?

Tags: high-voltage, opto-isolator, feedback, resonance

My team and I are designing an induction heater, and I've been asked to look into resonance sweeping so the microcontroller controlling our application can automatically find the resonant frequency. This would give peak efficiency and enable us to have accurate control of output power via duty cycle control.

I haven't even gotten to the microcontroller software/firmware side of things yet, but I know I'll have to measure the voltage across a tank capacitor rated for 1600Vdc/650Vac (C3 in the below circuit).

[image]

The frequency of the signal inspected should be under 100kHz, but making it work up to 200kHz would be a good bonus. The signal will have positive and negative voltage, but the negative voltage can be rectified out, like [this MIT kid did in his project](http://www.mit.edu/%7Emilesdai/projects/inductionheater/index.html):

[image]

Using a Zener diode for input protection is nice, but for a high-power application like ours, I'm not taking any chances. An opto-isolator is the way to go, I think. Ideally, a high-voltage sensing IC with opto-isolation. Haven't been able to find anything in the past half hour, so I thought I'd ask here before diving deeper.

Measuring current would be the most robust/accurate method, but finding something that will work up to 150kHz with 100A doesn't sound cheap. If anyone knows otherwise, please say.

Comment: *Sorry for the jargon* --> it's "engineering talk" so why are you apologizing? Maybe you are a manager (my team and I) so, maybe you should get an engineer to post if you are uncomfortable about standard eng-talk? Can you be more direct about your question? You seem to be saying it has to use an opto and it might be a high-voltage sensing IC but, truth be known; these are your decisions and don't explain what you are trying to achieve so, forget about proposing solutions that make no sense (to me at least) and concentrate on the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Was about to say the same: thanks for using the proper terminology! I just removed that apology; there was nothing to apologize for. Now the thing is, I'm not sure what you're actually asking about – asking for concrete component recommendations is explicitly off-topic here, so I'll assume your question is "how do I measure Vpp of a tank circuit in an isolated fashion". Is that right? Does your L3 per chance actually have a small secondary current sense winding? That would be kind of useful here.

Comment: You can use a specialized current sense amplifier placed at some appropriate place (like the above mentioned handy secondary winding). If you find one with a serial bus interface like SPI, you could use digital isolators instead of optocouplers, which might give more accurate results as you don't have to worry about stuff like analog current transfer ratios and general EMI.

Answer (score 0):

I've realized thanks to [this great website](http://www.richieburnett.co.uk/indheat.html) that measuring max voltage or current or whatever is not the way to go. Instead, I have to measure phase difference between source voltage and coil voltage.

Load voltage leading source voltage by 90degrees gives maximum power, and slightly more than 90degrees gives almost max power but, more importantly, zero voltage switching conditions so my inverter can do soft switching instead of hard switching and stay cool and safe.

I've seen an induction hob circuit using a voltage divider to accomplish this. I'll be rectifying the signal with a single diode because my topology is a little different and has negative voltages.

I'll be using an STM32, so I'll go out on a (short) limb here and say the ADC speed and resolution requirements for doing this are fulfilled.

Need to put this aside for a little while, anyways. Sorry I don't have my own schematic to upload.